# How can I check for malware in a Theme?

Tags: themes

There are so many free, freemium and premium Themes out there. How can I be sure that a Theme I download doesn't have malware in the code? Is there an (relatively) easy way to check for malicious code without going through every line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try using the theme check plugin at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/

Answer (score 3):

Antivirus Check for Wordpress themes: http://wpantivirus.com

Answer (score -1):

Make a cross file search for `eval`. If you find this one then the author (or someone who ripped it) has something to hide.

Comment: I make use of `eval` in a custom template engine while modifying dom trees. Does that mean I'm trying to hide something?

Comment: @Waldermort There's absolutely no need to use `eval` to modify DOM trees. You got `DOMElement` and `DOMDocument` for that. If this isn't possible, then you'll have to elaborate. Further: Read the question title. Then tell me this isn't a valid answer. Anyway, if you're using `eval`, then you're probably doing something wrong/misusing something.

Comment: After I have parsed a DOM tree (and stored references to nodes of interest), then merging that tree into another document, those references become invalid. I solved this by instead of storing a reference, I store the path ie. `->childNodes->item(2)`. After the whole DOM has been inserted into another document, I can quickly get a reference to those nodes using `eval`. Granted this can be done using arrays and loops (XPath has a lot of branching) but `eval` is much cleaner and easier to read. Your answer of `has something to hide` is plain wrong.

Comment: @Waldermort as we're already arguing about that :) ... I'm not able to imagine your setup completely - would have to see that in code and understand what your idea, task and goal is. You know that [WordPress got the Filesystem API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API)? And the [`DOM*` classes](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4944232) are really easy to use and much less expensive to search than with Regexes or than storing references in the DB. And then there's the separation of concerns: Such stuff doesn't belong in a theme. It's plugin material.

Comment: Since you mention it, my code is in a plugin, but could easily be extended to a theme. Infact, imagine a `twig` or `DJango` based theme. I make use of the DomDocument API directly in an effort to implement a template inheritance where HTML elements can be inserted into the main page by plugins (yes plugins for my plugin). Storing the path to a DomNode and later referencing with an `eval` enables me to use the same DOM across documents, store the state in WP's settings and perform expensive searches/validations only once. The same could be done with XPath with a performance cost.

Answer (score -1):

Look for   `<hidden>`  `<iframe>`  `<eval>`   `<height=0>` `<width=0>`

Lot's of real life detection for malicious injections in the website files: 
http://quttera.blogspot.co.il/search/label/Web%20malware%20scan%20reports%20and%20analysis

Look for similar stuff in your website files.

To do the whole sitecheck from your WP dashboard for exploits and malware use this one:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quttera-web-malware-scanner/

Comment: `hidden` can be used for form input fields, `eval` is used in template engines, `height=0` and `width=0` can be used to hide `screen reader` texts. You are misleading people into thinking that these strings are all malicious.

Comment: @Waldermort I believe it is obvious that my answer implied that NOT the tags THEMSELVES are malicious but that you might want to start from reviewing what's under the hood.